# Facebook Canvas Application iFrame OAuth 2.0 using Graph API

Tags: facebook, oauth, facebook-graph-api

Hi I need a latest tutorial on Authentication using the new Graph API and building an App with the graph API.
I am new to facebook Apps and wanted to build a HelloWorld App with basic functionalities like Authentication, Publishing etc.

Thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with the documentation on facebook: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api

Also you did not specify what language your tutorial should focus on? There is a huge difference for a tutorial depending on which programming language you choose. Also it shouldn't be too hard to google for such a tutorial.